# LibreOffice Calc: two documents with same font and size with different results

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I created two documents (meant to be front and back of a brochure) with LibreOffice Calc. I used the same font and size (Droid Sans size 10) for both and they came out of the printer in very different size.

What I tried: to make sure the right size was used, I marked the full text, changed the size (it visibly changed on screen) then changed it back to size 10 (again I could watch the change on screen). I did the same with the second text and saved both. They still came out very different.
I checked the printer setting but couldn't find any 'resize'-mode.
Any ideas, please? Thank you.

Comment: Check Menu Format -> Page -> Sheet Tab -> Scaling mode. See http://superuser.com/a/675286/84724

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I didn't know about that scaling mode and definitely didn't change it, so I wonder how it got to 85% in that one page. But at least it's now fixed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

User [tohuwawahu](https://askubuntu.com/users/20661/tohuwawohu) made [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789859/libreoffice-calc-two-documents-with-same-font-and-size-with-different-results#comment1186935_789859) suggesting that OP check

**Menu Format > Page > Sheet Tab > Scaling mode**

They also linked to [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/668040/how-to-scale-a-long-libreoffice-calc-sheet-to-fit-on-two-pages-when-exporting-to/675286#675286) which explains what the *Scaling Mode* setting does.

The OP [replied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789859/libreoffice-calc-two-documents-with-same-font-and-size-with-different-results#comment1187867_789859) that this suggestion fixed their problem: scaling had been set to 85% for one of their pages.